# Unable to fetch data from TempData

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

i am saving some value in `TempData` in my `controller_method`. but when i access it in `view` , i get nothing...

**Controller code:**

```
public ActionResult Read_Surah()
{
      TempData["Verse_Count"] = obj1.Total_Ayahs; // int data
      return Json(new { key = Records }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**view part:**

```
 $.ajax({
         url: "../Gateway/Admin_Mgmt?Action_Code=" + 115 + "&S_ID=" + surah_id,
         type: 'Post',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         dataType: 'json',
         async: false,
         data: '',
         success: function (result) 
               {
                   var mera_obj = result.key;  
                   contents = mera_obj;
                   mera_obj.size;
                    @{
                       string q = (string)TempData["Verse_Count"];
                     }
                     alert(@q);
                     return false;
                }, 
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("Error :   " + xhr.responseText);         },
          });
```

but its showing 'undefined' in alert...

Comment: flag the question correctly.this related mvc

Comment: Now, please provide the relevant info like where do you get the error, do you get an exception on the server's side? Did you try to debug? And why are you storing an int value in Verse_Count but expect to get it back as a string?

Comment: in controller it may looks like object. but in view you casted as "string " ?

Comment: you can't get it that way - you have to return a json object.

Comment: i tried to cast it as int but exception ...

Answer (score 1):

Do not use TempData to pass value from Controller to view.

Use ViewBag, as TempData is used to provide you data from controller to controller or Action to Action.

See the link for reference:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem